# Why does CMD ignore the character `;`?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, tokenize

I'm just wondering. When I type **`;`** in cmd, it will just ignore it.

I can type **`;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`** and it will do the same thing but, if I do **`;a`** it will say error.

Why is that?

[image: CMD ignoring <code>;</code>]

Comment: It's a delimiter for CMD. Note `dir/?` is legal because CMD separates the command from the parameters. However most programs, but not all, require parameters to be separated by spaces, so subsequent switches have to be separated because the program parses these.

Comment: @Flimzy **`;` doesn't end the command in cmd**. Only `&`, `&&` and `|` are used for multiple commands in the same line. `;` is just a delimiter like [`<space>` `<tab>` `;` `,` `=` `<0x0B>` `<0x0C>` and `<0xFF>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133/995714). `dir;/?` behaves just like `dir /?` instead of resulting in an error

Answer (score 2):

`;` is a delimiter.

Delimiters separate one parameter from the next - they split the command line up into words.

More info on https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

Answer (score 2):

The semicolon is not ignored by `cmd.exe`; rather is it even particularly recognised, namely as a token separator, which are used to separate commands from its arguments and arguments from each other. Here are all such characters:

- <kbd>SPACE</kbd> (code `0x20`)
- <kbd>TAB</kbd> (horizontal tabulator, code `0x09`)
- `,` (comma, code `0x2C`)
- `;` (semicolon, code `0x3B`)
- `=` (equal-to sign, code `0x3D`)
- <kbd>VTAB</kbd> (vertical tabulator, code `0x0B`)
- <kbd>FF</kbd> (form-feed or page-break, code `0x0C`)
- <kbd>NBSP</kbd> (non-breaking space, code `0xFF`)

Note that multiple consecutive token separators are collapsed to a single one.

Answer (score 0):

Command prompt does not ignore the character ";", ";" is a delimeter and cmd recognizes it as so so it doesn't "ignore" the character, but reads it similar to a space so nothing appears when you write it alone.